# Excel VBA - duplicate rows

Tags: excel, vba

I need to duplicate a row that is full of formulas N times.  N is defined by the number of rows on a different sheet.  The formulas are unique per row, but I think autofill will handle that.

In "DestSheet":
    Row 1 is a header
    Row 2 has the line I want to replicate "Cnt" times, starting in Row 3.
    Row 2 has cells that are unique to the row - =Credentials!C2
    I need Row 2 to be the same as row 2 but increment the row numbers
         So that I get =Credntials!C3 on row 3 and =Credentials!C4 on row 4
    (other formulas are more complex - but follow the same model)
    When the function is done, "DestSheet" will have "Cnt" rows of what started on line 2

I am close from code I found on this site.....

```
Sub AddRows(Cnt As Integer, DestName As String)

    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer


    Set DestSheet = Worksheets(DestName)

    For i = 1 To Cnt

        Sheets(DestName).cell(i + 2, 1).AutoFill _
              Destination:=Range(LastRow)
    Next i
End Sub ' AddRows
```

Comment: What is `Range(LastRow)`

Comment: Do you know how to use your `Sub`? Do you know that in order to call it you need to create a separate sub?

Comment: Yes - this is a sub that will be called by other subroutines, that is why I pass in parameters.  I am an old C programmer (pre-Visual C, C++, etc).  But new to VBA.  I am struggling with some of the methods and how they work.  Is there a reason I should not use called sub routines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop with autofill:

```
Sub AddRows(Cnt As Integer, DestName As String)

    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
    Set DestSheet = Worksheets(DestName)

    DestSheet.Cells(2, 1).AutoFill _
              Destination:=DestSheet.Cells(2, 1).Resize(Cnt)

End Sub
```

The above will fill A2 down to the number Rows in CNT.  If you want to fill the whole row 2 down, use this.

```
Sub AddRows(Cnt As Integer, DestName As String)

    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
    Set DestSheet = Worksheets(DestName)
    Dim colcnt As Long
    With DestSheet
        colcnt = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, colcnt)).AutoFill _
              Destination:=.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, colcnt)).Resize(Cnt)
    End With
End Sub
```

AS ZygD explained, Because of the variable in the Sub line, this cannot run on its own it must be called.

```
Sub CallAddRows()
Dim rwcnt as integer
dim DestShtNme as String

rwcnt = 20
DestShtNme = "Sheet1" 'Change to your sheet.

AddRows rwcnt, DestShtNme

End Sub
```

I assume in your code you are iterating through various sheets and calling this sub to send to add lines.  The above is just an example. How you come up with the two variables to pass into the AddRows sub is up to you.  The important part is that the variable get passed to the sub.

Comment: And now it's even more worth upvoting! The answer is correct, but I just doubt if the OP knows how to call this kind of sub (he said he found the code on this site, but he didn't say he knew how to use it). It requires parameters to be stated and it can only be done from another sub.

Comment: @ZygD Yes, I assumed that the OP knows what they are doing, but I added a quick blurb to my edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
sub x()
NbrRows = Sheets(SrcName).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  ' get the number of rows on the  sheet to know how many rows to add to the dest sheet
If NbrRows > 1 Then
    Call AddRows(NbrRows, DestName)
End If

end sub

Sub AddRows(Cnt As Integer, DestName As String)

Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
Dim Dest As String


Set DestSheet = Worksheets(DestName)
' DestSheet.Activate

Dest = "3:" & Cnt

Sheets(DestName).Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(DestName).Rows(Dest).Select
Sheets(DestName).Paste
Sheets(DestName).Range("A2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

End Sub ' AddRows